# Find $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac1{\ln^2n}\left( \frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} +\cdots + \frac{\ln n}{n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have to find the following limit:

> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} + \cdots + \frac{\ln n}{n}}{\ln^2n}$$

I tried splitting this limit like so:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} + \cdots + \frac{\ln n}{n}}{\ln n} \cdot \dfrac{1}{\ln n}$$

Because $\dfrac{1}{\ln n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$, I concluded that the limit is $0$. I know that in order to use this I firstly would have to show that

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} + \cdots +\frac{\ln n}{n}}{\ln n}$$

is bounded, but I didn't know how to do that and kinda hoped for the best. It turns out that my hopes were in vain, since the limit is actually $\dfrac{1}{2}$ and not $0$, like I got. I also tried using Stolz-Cesaro, resulting in:

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\ln (n+1)}{n+1}}{\ln^2 (n + 1) - \ln^2 n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\ln (n+1)}{n + 1}}{(\ln (n+1)-\ln n)(\ln (n + 1) + \ln n)}$$

$$= \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \dfrac{\frac{\ln (n + 1)}{n + 1}}{\ln (\frac{n + 1}{n}) \cdot \ln(n(n + 1))}$$

Aaand I got stuck.

So how should I approach this **and** get $\dfrac{1}{2}$ as the final answer?

Comment: Hint: $(n+1)\ln{\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac{n+1}{n}\frac{f(1/n)-f(0)}{1/n} \rightarrow f’(0)=1$, where $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define
$$
S_n=\frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} + ... + \frac{\ln n}{n}
$$

The function $\ln(x)/x$ is decreasing for $x\geq 3$, so
$$
\frac{\ln 2}{2} + \int_3^n\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx  \leq S_n\leq \frac{\ln 2}{2} + \frac{\ln 3}{3} + \int_3^{n}\frac{\ln(x)}{x}\,dx,
$$
$$
\frac{\ln(2)}{2} + \frac{\ln(n)^2}{2}-\frac{\ln(3)^2}{2}\leq S_n\leq\frac{\ln(2)}{2}+\frac{\ln(3)}{3} + \frac{\ln(n)^2}{2}-\frac{\ln(3)^2}{2}.
$$
Now divide through by $\ln(n)^2$ and apply the squeeze theorem to conclude
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{S_n}{\ln(n)^2}=\frac{1}{2}.
$$

Comment: I'm sorry but I've never done what you did there before and I'm a bit confused. How exactly did you convert from $\sum\limits_{k=3}^n \frac{\ln k}{k}$ to the integral $\int_3^n \frac{\ln(x)}{x} dx$ ? Is it a Riemann Sum? I'm new to that concept, so if it is, I don't see it. Secondly, even with that conversion explained, how exactly did you arrive at that first inequality? I have proved for myselft on paper that $\frac{\ln(x)}{x}$ is indeed decreasing for $x \ge 3$ (it is for $x \ge e$), but I don't see how that leads to your first inequality. Could you please provide a little more detail?

Comment: If a function $f(x)$ is decreasing on $[a,b]$ (where $a\le b$ are integers), then a left-hand Riemann sum for $\int_a^b f(x)\,dx$ will be an overestimate and a right-hand sum will be an underestimate. In particular, for $\Delta x = 1$, there are bounds $\sum_{n=a}^{b-1} f(n)\ge\int_a^b f(x)\,dx\ge\sum_{n=a+1}^b f(n)$. These inequalities directly give $\ln(3)/3+\ldots+\ln(n)/n\ge\int_3^{n+1}\ln(x)/x\,dx>\int_3^{n}\ln(x)/x\,dx$ and $\ln(4)/4+\ldots+\ln(n)/n\le\int_3^{n}\ln(x)/x\,dx$. The bounds I gave come from this by making some adjustments for missing terms.

Comment: Thanks for that explanation, I understood it much better now. Just one more question: What happens if $\Delta x$ is not equal to $1$? That first inequality you gave in your comment was based on the assumption that $\Delta x = 1$ . Are we allowed to set $\Delta x = 1$ whenever we want? Or how did you get there?

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct. At the end you need to rewrite your expression as $$\dfrac{\log n+\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)}{\dfrac{n+1}{n}\cdot n\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\cdot \left(2\log n+\log\left(1+\dfrac{1}{n}\right)\right)}$$ Dividing the numerator and denominator by $\log n$ you can easily see that the numerator tends to $1$ and denominator tends to $2$ and you are done.

---

We have made use of the fact that $\log n\to\infty$ and $n\log(1+(1/n))\to 1$ as $n\to\infty $.